# Blender 3.5 Eevee Volumetrics Horizontal Artefacts or banding

Tags: 3d-view

[image]I attached a picture with an imported VDB file, wich has, in Viewport and in final render also, some kind of horizontal banding. See the highlighted areas please. Any solution for this maybe? Thank you for your time.